# Creating a date slicer with fixed values in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I'm working a Power BI where the data model has a column for dates. I need to create a slicer in such a way that it filters my data to specific dates.

One of my ideas was to create a second table of the form:

| Interval | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Today | 2023-11-24 | 2023-11-25 |
| Week | 2023-11-20 | 2023-11-25 |
| Month | 2023-11-01 | 2023-11-25 |
| Cycle | 2023-07-01 | 2023-11-25 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And then create a slicer for the dates with those values as the start and end points, however, I don't know how to make it affect the original table and how to make it into buttons, I'm only able to get the slider.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but Power BI relationships just can't express the relationship between your Interval table and the Date table.

Instead add columns to the Date table itself like "IsToday", "IsThisMonth", etc.

Or have your Interval table enumerate all the dates in each interval and have a bidirectional cross filter with your date table.